# ChallengeAsync() from HttpContext does not redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

We have a javascript app "wrapped" in an ASP Core MVC Application. Each AJAX-request from the javascript app hits a controller decorated with [Authorize].

In our startup method we've defined an AuhenticationScheme pointing toward our Identity Server. And then another scheme for the cookies that they are ultimately signed in as.

To ensure that all requests coming in are authenticated we use the following:

```
 app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    string auth = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(auth) ||     !auth.StartsWith("Bearer ", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        await context.ChallengeAsync("oidce", new     AuthenticationProperties {
                             RedirectUri = "/"
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await next();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    await next();
                }
            });
```

Now if the cookie expires it triggers the "ChallengeAsync" - that doesn't really work if the call originated from an AJAX request made from the browser. I thought since I had the context here that it would simply override the AJAX and make the browser start the round-trip.

Is there a way to say to the browser that "no, this isn't an AJAX-response, go where I tell you to"?

Comment: How did you expect this to work? Ajax calls shouldn't be redirected since most clients (other then browser) doesn't follow redirects on authentication failure. Ajax and restclients etc. expect http status codes 401 / 403 for Unauthorized and Forbidden respectively and once they receive, the client decides what to do (ask user to relog, ignore it, close the application whatever, notify the user etc). For MVC apps its common to be redirected to the login page when one isnt authenticated

Comment: I guess it depends on what you define as a client. Since this API basically also wraps the javascript-application and handles all the request processing.

For instance if I were to call context.Redirect("/") in app.Use() I would assume the browser honors that no matter if the original call was made with Ajax.

Comment: Yes, but even it would redirect, when you do an ajax call you usually expect json or xml response. When an auth challange comes, you are redirected to the login page and you would receive html instead which your ajax call can't interpret anyways. So what would be the point? You just have to treat ajax calls differently (return 401) rather than an redirect to the login page. Your API just needs to return 401 on ajax / api endpoints, the ajax clients needs to read the http status code and then react (i.e. by triggering the auth process **on the client** in case you use SPA or just reload)

Comment: But you could of course always check via `HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"` if the request originates from ajax or not and then trigger a challenge or send 401 unauthorized status code

Comment: Thank you, that's basically what I came up with too.
Originally I wanted to avoid having to send the access_token via the browser to the javascript client (hence the API-wrapper). Will have to come up with another strategy of implementing this or rewrite it to be an implicit client instead of the hybrid it currently is.

Answer (score 1):

As Tseng pointed out in the comments I implemented almost to the letter.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    if (context.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
                    {
                        // webapp will then do a location.reload() which triggers the auth
                        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string auth = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(auth) || !auth.StartsWith("Bearer ", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            await context.ChallengeAsync();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await next();
                        }
                    }  
                }
                else
                {
                    await next();
                }
            });
```

The javascript application then catches the Ajax exception and checks if the status is 401 and simply does **window.location.reload()**

Not an elegant solution, will probably rewrite in the future but it solves the immediate problem.